# What kind of port/connector is this?

Tags: honda, audio, fit

[image]
I just bought honda fit also known as jazz 1.3 hybrid 2011 from japan.But its manual is in Japanese and i just want to know what kind(name) of port/connector it is. Its under cigarette lighter and av cable socket.

Comment: What is the size of this connector?

Comment: Its width is approx 2.8 cm and height is .7 cm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a Honda diagnostic port.  A "JDM" Japanese vehicle that will never see the states is not required to have a standard OBD2 connector.

I have a Snap-On Solus diagnostic computer, and I believe I have that adapter - there was a time when I had money that I was collecting all of them, regardless if I would ever use it.

Although yours may - some OEMS install an OBD2 port *and* their own proprietary connector with advanced capabilities beyond the typical OBD mode spectrum.  The ability to re-flash the Engine Control Module (ECM/ECU) to new software, for instance.

On Edit:

I now think I'm completely wrong.  That (under the AV system) is possibly some sort of HDMI port.  I have no idea whether it's an input or an output.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Can you tell me exact name or part number of this port as I searched online and not find nothing about this.Or from where can i buy it online.

Comment: Why would you want to buy it?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am just curious about things,my honda fit have no aux,usb and only thing i play is cd which is quite outdated.I was hoping that this port has something to do with audio/video of car media player.